# Extract string within first two quotation marks using regular expressions?

Tags: r, regex

There is a vector of strings that looks like the following (text with two or more substrings in quotation marks):

```
vec <- 'ab"cd"efghi"j"kl"m"'
```

The text within the first pair of quotation marks (cd) contains a useful identifier (cd is the desired output). I have been studying how to use regular expressions but I haven't learned how to find the first and second occurrences of something like quotation marks.

Here's how I have been getting cd:

```
tmp <- strsplit(vec,split="")[[1]]
paste(tmp[(which(tmp=='\"')[1]+1):(which(tmp=='\"')[2]-1)],collapse="")
"cd"
```

My question is, is there another way to find "cd" using regular expressions? in order to learn more how to use them. I prefer base R solutions but will accept an answer using packages if that's the only way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match everything except `"` then capture everything upto next `"` and replace captured group by itself.

```
gsub( '[^"]*"([^"]*).*', '\\1', vec)

[1] "cd"
```

For detailed explanation of regex you can see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/CQmMZO/1)

Comment: Perfect thank you. That was fast: "you must wait 7 minutes to accept this answer". Now to work on understanding how it works.

Comment: Glad that it helped @Baroque, you can accept answers only a threshold has been passed.  I have added explanation that how it works.  Hope that helps too :)

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't return "km"? I thought pattern matching was "greedy" and would math the last possible match.

Comment: @IRTFM, sir it will return only the string matched between first 2 `"` as it will match (not capture everything upto first `"` then `"` then capture everything except `"` (i.e. second `"`).  Hope it is clear now

Comment: Why don't you need to use either a "^" to anchor at the beginning or use a "?" to convert greedy to lazy regex matching?

Comment: What I was calling "greedy" is apparently different than your use of the term. I thought "greedy" meant matching the last possible portion of the string which I thought would be "km".

Comment: @IRTFM, you are thinking it correctly.  The matching is indeed greedy.  But it did not cross second `"` because I used `[^"]`  (everything except `"`) instead of `.` (i.e. everything).  So it matched to any length of string but only upto whenever second `"` was matched and it stopped there.  So matching is indeed greedy and not lazy.  That is not a positive/negative lookahead.  If I would have used lookaheads it would have went upto last `"` matched.